# Adding Edit and Delete buttons in each row in listview in android

Tags: android

Hi in the below code we had created a listview .In the Screen contains one add button .If we press the button data will send as json request and get the response from the server.

If the response is successfull then I am adding each row add and delete button for each row.

can any one help me where i did  the mistake

```
public class AddBuildingFragement extends Fragment {

    EditText et_building;
    TextView Add,mTitle,delete;
    ListView lv;
    String name;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;



    public AddBuildingFragement() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        //((NavigationViewActivity) getActivity ( )).setActionBarTitle ("LIGHT CONTROL");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_building, container, false);


        init(rootView);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void clickListener() {
        Add.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                name=et_building.getText ().toString ();
                String level="1";
//                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity ());
//                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
//                progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
//                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
//                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
//                progressDialog.show();



                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(API.URL_BASE)
                        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                API service = retrofit.create(API.class);

                try{
                    JSONObject parmobject=new JSONObject ();
                    parmobject.put("name",name);
                    parmobject.put("level",level);
                    Call <NewBuilding> userCall = service.getbuildinglist (parmobject.toString());
                    userCall.enqueue(new Callback <NewBuilding> () {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<NewBuilding> call, Response <NewBuilding> response) {

//                            if (progressDialog != null)
//                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Integer response1= response.code();
                            Log.d ("response", String.valueOf (response1));
                            if (response !=null && response.isSuccessful()&&response.code()==200) {

                                String status=response.body ().getStatus ();

                                if(status.equalsIgnoreCase ("success")){
                                    makeText(getActivity (), "Building successfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    arrayList.add (name);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();

                                }


                            } else {
                                makeText(getActivity (), "Invalid EmailId and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<NewBuilding> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });


    }

    private void init(View rootView) {
        et_building=(EditText)rootView.findViewById (R.id.build_name);
        Add=(TextView)rootView.findViewById (R.id.addbuild);
        //delete=(TextView)rootView.findViewById (R.id.delete_item);
        lv=(ListView)rootView.findViewById (R.id.list_building);
        arrayList=new ArrayList<String> ();
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity (),R.layout.building_listview_item,arrayList);
         MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(arrayList, this);

        //handle listview and assign adapter
        //ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_listview);
        //lView.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        clickListener();
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: after pressing add button no data is displaying

Comment: Make sure in the response you are getting the list.

Also please try to call `notifyDataSetChanged ();`method in side adapter and not in activity.

So you can create a public method in adapter send whole list there, modify list in adapter and notify for the data change there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is coming from `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` as it is not working. **Here** :-

```
if(status.equalsIgnoreCase ("success")){
    makeText(getActivity (), "Building successfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    arrayList.add (name);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();

}
```

---

**Possible Fix #1** : Clone the base method in your Adapter class as :

```
public void notifyDataSetChangedCustom(List<String> newdata) {
    mData.clear();
    mData.addAll(newdata);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And call `adapter.notifyDataSetChangedCustom(newdata)` instead of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`

---

**Possible Fix #2** : If still, it doesn't work, **stop** using only `notifyDataSetChanged`. Instead, try re-initializing the adapter & then call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

```
AttendanceAdapter adapter = new AttendanceAdapter(this, attendanceItems);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

---

**Possible Fix #3**: You're getting a null response from Retrofit. I think there might be 3 causes,

1. Target Server is not responding
2. You forgot to add `Internet` Permission.
3. *The Invisible Killer* **ClearTextTraffic** introduced on Android Pie : Fix by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your `<application>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Are you really getting the response? Try to check that & also if your click event is working

Also checj, if `status.equalsIgnoreCase ("success")` condition is satisfied

Comment: @Toaster request is going on but response is null

Comment: Yeah, there is your problem. The condition is never satisfied. You better check the Retrofit area.

Comment: where i did the mistake?

Comment: Only you can find the mistake. What you need to do is, use any proxy software like Fiddler & tunnel your wifi traffic through your computer. Then monitor if requests are successfully executed or not. 

But, first try to check things by simple logcat outputs.

Comment: Wait a minute, I think I found something. Updating the answer.

Comment: check fix #3 @jyothidadi

Comment: Then try the proxy process.

Comment: How to do ? I dont have any idea about proxy process